# How can I "jump" into stackframe from exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, exception

Having a raised `exception` I would like to jump into that frame. To explain better what I mean I wrote this mwe:

Assuming I have the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import sys

# Setup debugger
def raiseDebugger(*args):
    """ http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287-automatically-start-the-
    debugger-on-an-exception/ """

    import traceback, pdb
    traceback.print_exception(*args)
    pdb.pm()

sys.excepthook = raiseDebugger


# Now start with the question

def faulty(i):
    return 1 / i


with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(faulty, range(6))
```

which unsurprisingly leads to:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "test2.py", line 19, in faulty
    return 1 / i
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 23, in <module>
    pool.map(faulty, range(6))
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/bin/conda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
> /home/bin/conda/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py(608)get()
-> raise self._value
(Pdb)
```

Now to debug the problem I would like to "jump" into the frame which originally raised the `exception` (`ZeroDivisionError`).

The original exception is still available under `self._value` complete with `self._value.__traceback__`.

Answer (score 1):

The call that `pm` (or `post_mortem`) calls is from the value field of [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), and the default invocation of `post_mortem` is done on the `__traceback__` of that value.  However if you want to get to the underlying object, you want to access its `__context__` instead.  Given this code example:

```
import pdb
import sys
import traceback

def top():
    value = 1
    raise Exception('this always fails')

def bottom():
    try:
        top()
    except Exception as bot_ex:
        x = {}
        return x['nothing']

try:
    bottom()
except Exception as main_ex:
    pdb.post_mortem()
```

Running the code.  The `main_ex` would be analogous to your `self._value`.

```
> /tmp/foo.py(14)bottom()
-> return x['nothing']
(Pdb) main_ex
KeyError('nothing',)
(Pdb) pdb.post_mortem(main_ex.__traceback__)
> /tmp/foo.py(14)bottom()
-> return x['nothing']
```

Note we have a new pdb prompt at the same location, which is where the exception was originally raised.  Let's try it with `__context__` if we need to go further up:

```
(Pdb) c
(Pdb) pdb.post_mortem(main_ex.__context__.__traceback__)
> /tmp/foo.py(7)top()
-> raise Exception('this always fails')
```

If needed, keep repeating until you get to the target context/traceback desired.

---

Now for the multiprocessing case, which I wasn't aware would have made this much difference, as the question implies something general (How can I “jump” into stackframe from exception?), but it turns out the specifics in `multiprocessing` made all the difference.

In Python 3.4 a workaround was done to just show that traceback as a string; due to how much stuff a traceback actually has, communicating all that proved to be difficult as discussed in the [issue 13831](http://bugs.python.org/issue13831Ups) on the Python tracker, so instead a hack was done to bring a `__cause__` attribute into the current exception, but it is no full `__traceback__` as it just has the string representation of that, as I had suspected.

Anyway this is what would have happened:

```
(Pdb) !import pdb
(Pdb) !self._value.__cause__
RemoteTraceback('\n"""\nTraceback (most recent call last):...',)
(Pdb) !type(self._value.__cause__)
<class 'multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback'>
(Pdb) !self._value.__cause__.__traceback__
(Pdb) !self._value.__cause__.__context__
```

So this isn't actually possible until they figure out how to bring all those states across process boundaries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did try it with my example however `self._value.__context__` is `None`. Is this due to the fact that the exception was raised in instead of reraised (raise without argument)?

Comment: Oh, hmm, the remote traceback looks like a string though, but given what you got (the exception being `self._value`) you might want to just do it with `self._value.__traceback__`.  Sorry for not making my answer a bit more clear.

Comment: I tried that. However it loads the frame with `raise self._value` in the main process. I guess this is a limitation due to multiprocessing. I definitely learned something from your answer and will accept it unless somebody finds a way for my problem within the next day.